# Динамическая подгрузка маркеров в видимую область карты при ее перемещении в Openlayers / OSM?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

Использую Openlayers для работы с картами OSM. В БД сохранены данные маркеров. Как реализовать подгрузку данных (AJAX) исходя из видимой области карты. Т.е. как конкретно определить саму эту видимую область и как с ней работать для формирования запроса к БД?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы определить координаты (границы) видимой области карты в Openlayers есть метод [getExtend()](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getExtent).

Этот метод вернет вам две точки. Широта и долгота этих точек отображают четыре границы. Одна точка: северную и западную, а вторая - южную и восточную (скорее всего, точно не помню).

Следовательно у вас будет четыре значения:

1. Максимальная широта (севернее),
2. Минимальная широта (южнее),
3. Максимальная долгота (западнее),
4. Минимальная долгота (восточнее).

Чтобы получить маркеры видимой области, нужно отобрать все точки по такому принципу:

1. Широта выбираемых точек должна быть между минимальным и максимальным значением широты границ.
2. Долгота должна быть между максимальным и минимальным значением долготы границ.

Также необходимо учитывать, что широта может быть северная и южная, а долгота - западная и восточная, в зависимости от того в каком полушарии находиться точка (северном или южном и западном или восточном, соответственно)